Failure to correctly display languages ​other than English when converting html to pdf using html2pdf
In my project, I need to convert html to pdf. The language of my website is Farsi. The code I have to convert html to pdf and download it:
I added fonts to html2pdf and also Base64 but the Farsi text is displayed messed up.
How can I solve this problem? Do you have any suggestions for me?
  downloadPdf = () => {
    const element = this.contentRef.current;

    const options = {
        margin: 0.5,
        filename: 'downloaded.pdf',
        image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
                margin: { top: '20mm', right: '20mm', bottom: '20mm', left: '20mm' },
        html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
        jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' },
    };

    html2pdf()
        .from(element)
        .set(options)
        .toPdf()
        .get('pdf')
        .then((pdf) => {
          try {
            pdf.addFileToVFS('/styles/font/IRANSans(FaNum).ttf', IRANSANSBase64);
            pdf.addFont('/styles/font/IRANSans(FaNum).ttf', 'IRANSansFaNum', 'normal');
            pdf.setFont('IRANSansFaNum');
            pdf.setFontSize(12);
            pdf.save('downloaded.pdf');
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error generating PDF:", error);
          }
        });
  };


IRANSANSBase64:

react": ^18.3.1
html2canvas: ^1.4.1
html2pdf.js: ^0.10.2
